# how do i convert stl files into 2d images?

Tags: rendering

How do I do this? I've never used blender, and I'm only using this for a project that I need references (images) for. I saw a post on the forums asking something along the lines of this, but it was for SVG files.

Comment: Hello Captain :). What you're talking about sounds suspiciously like *rendering*. You render a 3D model to get a 2D image.